# How to update wp_posts with just the returned comment count from wp_comments (SQL GROUP BY)

Tags: posts, comments, mysql

I am doing a special migration from someone's custom CMS to a WP installation.  I successfully got the posts and comments migrated into their respective tables.  Now I need to get the comment count into the wp_posts table for each matching id.  I have something like this.  I'm close, I think:

```
SELECT COUNT(comment_content) AS total_comments, comment_post_ID AS commentID
FROM wp_comments
GROUP BY comment_post_ID;
--mysql won't let me run the group by on just the returned count column, so I'm stuck with    two columns of data when I just want to insert one

UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_count = total_comments WHERE wp_posts.ID = commentID;
--So I tried to set my returned data to variables and assign them into the update statement..which doesn't work
```

Anyway, perhaps I need to iterate all the posts, find a matching ID and update it by moving the cursor?  Or is there an easier way i'm missing somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I finally figured it out.  For those who want to know how something like this is handled with MySQL, here it is:

```
    UPDATE wp_posts, (SELECT COUNT(comment_content) AS total_comments, comment_post_ID
FROM wp_comments
GROUP BY comment_post_ID) x
       SET wp_posts.comment_count = x.total_comments
       WHERE wp_posts.ID = x.comment_post_ID;
```

Comment: That doesn't account for deleted or spam comments. You need to only count comments with comment_approved = '1'.

Comment: Good point.  Though I was doing this from a custom built CMS.  So the comments either existed or didn't.  No spam or deleted status.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to just write PHP to go through all the posts and call `wp_update_comment_count()` on each post ID.

Comment: But let's say I really wanted to figure this out with MySQL.  Any idea how?